# Where would be a good place to start for learning how to make visualizer-esque programs?

Tags: javascript, graphics

I've had trouble knowing what to google for tutorials or books.

Here are some examples of something in the realm of what I would like to make:

http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/voronoi-experiment/

http://www.chromeexperiments.com/detail/plane-deformations/

http://jsdo.it/clockmaker/particle

I would ideally like to build them in Javascript. So I realize this question is kind of vague, but the answer can be too. I just want an idea of what math related topics to study up on, or if there are any books on 'visual programming' that I should read. (I don't mean visual programming as in programming...well, visually as opposed to via text, more topics relating to the creation of shapes and patterns programmatically.)

Any help would be appreciated, and I can clarify if you would like.

EDIT: Just found this:

http://wonderfl.net/c/x9a3

So cool. On another note, I've worked with Flash and as a result, as3 for the past year. So I'm used to working with images that I've already created. I'm a total stranger to creating shapes and patterns with pure programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [Processing](http://processing.org/).  It's by no means a complete answer to your question(s) but it will give you some useful insights.  The Shop page of their site provides details of books which may be of interest to you,

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Do you really think the information will carry over to a language like javascript? Because ultimately I'm not going to work with processing. From the website it does seem like it's sort of learning language anyway. If that's the case, I'm prepared to buy the book. Awesome. 

Edit: http://processingjs.org/

That looks like the perfect solution. What do you know.

Answer (score 1):

Nice list of cool visuals!

Another great place to look for examples (not a tutorial) is [Shader Toy](http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/), which uses GLSL shaders via WebGL, under Javascript. Note that to get WebGL to work in a browser, you need a [very new browser](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Getting_a_WebGL_Implementation).

If you're interested in shaders, which you probably are if you want to do real-time visualizations, there are [several good tutorials](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=glsl+shaders+tutorial&ei=UTF-8&fr=moz35).

**Edit:** I should add that if you're just looking to get *started,* you don't need graphics acceleration (such as GLSL); that's probably more complexity than you need, and you lose portability (until WebGL makes it into more mainstream browser releases). Obviously you can do pretty well just with HTML 5 canvas (as in processing.js, or those Chrome experiments). Keeping in mind that HTML 5 canvas, while more widespread than WebGL, is [not ubiquitous among web surfers](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/46_of_internet_users_ready_for_html5.php) either (46% in May).